# Liquibase Linux: Cannot find database driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, liquibase

I'm on Ubuntu, using MySQL Connector/J 8.0.22. I'm using the following properties in **liquibase.properties**:

```
classpath: /home/bence/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.22/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar

driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Permissions are granted for the library. Full message:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot
> find database driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Would need a bit more context.  What is the exact command you are running to initiate a liquibase update?  I notice it is a maven repo path you are using for the classpath, so are you running liquibase directly or through a maven goal?  Also, would need complete log for context, this could not be the root error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver